# wget with Variables in URL in Windows Batch

Tags: batch-file, wget

I'm trying to download files with wget in a windows batch file using variables in url.

Here's my code example

```
set gpsweek=2202
set weekday=1
wget http://ftp.aiub.unibe.ch/CODE/COD%gpsweek%%weekday%.EPH_M
```

This doesn't works. But

```
wget http://ftp.aiub.unibe.ch/CODE/COD22021.EPH_M
```

works.
So i guess it's something with the string. I tried to use some " " around the string, but it also doesn't work.

Before wget i used curl and i had no problems with the arguments.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.
Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a Good way to see why something *"doesn't work"* in `batch-file`s is to debug the code. One way is to use `echo`. You can simply `echo` the line to see if the result is what you expect it to be. If it is not, then you can rectify it.

Variables are sensitive to whitespace. We need to ensure we do not include any of them, even accidently. To do that, simply enclose the variables during `set` in double quotes from before the variable name until the end of the value `set "var=value"`

So your code should work as expected by simply running it with the double quotes:

```
@echo off
set "gpsweek=2202"
set "weekday=1"
wget "http://ftp.aiub.unibe.ch/CODE/COD%gpsweek%%weekday%.EPH_M"
:: for debugging purposes, we echo the URL, this can be removed in production
echo "http://ftp.aiub.unibe.ch/CODE/COD%gpsweek%%weekday%.EPH_M"
```